# Getting rid of the icon in the Windows 7 system tray that shows you the hidden system tray programs

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

How do you get rid of the icon in the Windows 7 system tray that shows you the hidden system tray programs?

[image]

When you click on this icon you see the system tray programs that you've selected to hide.  I could have sworn I've done this on other systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on that icon, it should show you a link called "Customize..." Click that and you will be show a menu that says *Select which icons and notifications appear on the taskbar*.

Click on the box below that says **Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar**. It will then display all system tray icons on the taskbar.

[image]

Comment: +1 beat me to it. well, here's my screen shot. :)

Comment: @Molly - I just happen to be looking at that menu when I saw the question. Thanks for the screenshot! :D

Comment: @lsxek I want to *not* display the icons I've selected to hide and also *not* show that icon above.  I want both hidden.  Can do?

Comment: @Howiecamp - No Can do! :) however, there are programs and registry hacks to completely hide/remove system tray icons.